# How can I randomly choose to do an action or not based on a Poisson distribution model?

Tags: c++, random, simulation, poisson

I want to simulate the behavior of an employee who may goes and drinks a cup of coffee after he finishes one task based on a Poisson distribution model and on average every hour. I am trying to use the std::poisson_distribution to simulate this process, but this class gives me some random number based on the given average and the Poisson distribution model. I want the behavior of the employee to be random and when he finishes his task, then he decides to go and rest or not. Does anyone know if it is possible to achieve this behavior using the std::poisson_distribution and how?

Comment: The std::poison_distribution takes an int as the mean, and returns an integer frequency. If you use 1, then the low frequency output will be restricted to zero. Better to use 24 times/ day. If t is the number of minutes since the last coffee (expressed as a double), the frequency,f, is 24*60/t. Get a random number, n, from the distribution. If f < n  the worker goes. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/poisson_distribution

Comment: @DS_London The mean of a Poisson need not be an int, but the outcomes are.  The Poisson is a counting distribution, the mean represents the average count per unit time (or space).  The average of a bunch of ints is not necessarily an int.

Comment: @pjs I take your point. What was trying to get to is that if you have 1 or even 1.0 as the mean, the outcomes of the generator will be 0,1,2,3 etc. By increasing the mean to 24, you get more definition of the outcomes.

Comment: @DS_London Statisticians like to say "the Poisson scales", which is also a "dad joke" if you know some French.